# Why this javascript program is being returned as undefined?

Tags: javascript, recursion, while-loop

```
  function sum(n) {
     var result = 0;
     while (n > 0) {
      result = result + n;
      n = n - 1;
     }
    }
   sum(3)
```

This should be 6 but it's being returned as undefined

Comment: no return statement

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you need to insert the `return` statement.

```
  function sum(n) {
     var result = 0;
     while (n > 0) {
      result = result + n;
      n = n - 1;
     }
    return result;
    }
   sum(3)
```